# Docker run command throws and error message

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am using docker to build and run my .Net Core 3.1 console application. It is a simple Hello World application:

```cs
using System;

namespace DockerTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTesting"]
```

It is also very simple one, which just take the base image and copy the app into the WORKDIR. I use Powershell to build and run the image.

```sh
PS ~: docker build -t testingdocker .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.168kB
Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
 ---> 6bb83e9aa359
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in 4c3319712cf8
Removing intermediate container 4c3319712cf8
 ---> cf1ab373e085
Step 3/4 : COPY . .
 ---> 1c6a846459d8
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTesting"]
 ---> Running in 56e335f09bc2
Removing intermediate container 56e335f09bc2
 ---> 2ef84c282ac0
Successfully built 2ef84c282ac0
Successfully tagged testingdocker:latest
PS ~: docker run testingdocker
```

after trying to run the image I get the following error message:

```sh
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-DockerTesting does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

But when I run the application through VS it works like a charm.

Comment: Can you try ["dotnet", "DockerTesting.dll"] ?

Comment: @bugrakosen I did. Still the same message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at the [sample Dockerfile for .NET Core applications](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/) in the Docker documentation.

In your Dockerfile you're missing the build (and publish part), which one normally wants to be done as part of the Docker build process. Also, you're missing the `.dll` at the end of the project name in the `ENTRYPOINT`.

Try replacing yours with something similar to this one (some routes may need to be adjusted, this assumes the Dockerfile is placed at .csproj level and the project has no other dependencies):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy .csproj and restore
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and publish
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTesting.dll"]
```

Comment: Perfect, now it works. Thank you very much. But now I have another question: why when I ran the application through VS it worked fine? doesn't it go through my DockerFile?

Comment: By default it doesn't, normally VS just runs it directly on your host, unless you've specifically configured to use Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Check the correct case for Entry point file Name

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "**DotNetTesting**.dll"]

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd put this out there, though it's probably a niche use case.

I had amended my Dockerfile to install a bunch of dotnet's monitoring tools:

```
RUN dotnet tool install --tool-path /tools dotnet-trace \
 && dotnet tool install --tool-path /tools dotnet-counters \
 && dotnet tool install --tool-path /tools dotnet-dump \
 && dotnet tool install --tool-path /tools dotnet-gcdump

# [...]

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

WORKDIR /tools
COPY --from=publish /tools .
```

Now, my problem was that I copied the tools *after* `/app/publish`, so what happened was that my entrypoint looked for my binary in the `/tools` directory instead of `/app`.

Swapping the two solved the issue:

```
WORKDIR /tools
COPY --from=publish /tools .

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
```

Also, this problem didn't manifest itself until I threw away the container and rebuilt it, which left me very confused, because things broke down all of a sudden.